# How Can I determine "weeks" using DateTime

Tags: c#

I have a start date column called `StartDate` in a database table. I need to determine how many weeks elapsed from the start date until today.

Here is my code:

```
DateTime startDate = new DateTime(StartedDate);
if (startDate.addDays(7) == DateTime.Today) {
    // One week elapsed.
}
```

Let's say `startDate` is 9/29/2016. If I add 7 days, the total becomes 10/7/2016.
If, for example, today is 10/7/2016 - the same date as above, so there is 1 week from the start date. How can I determine the number of weeks for dates in the future?

Comment: SO is not a homework service. Do it yourself.

Comment: Im doing it myself. I just need comments to correct me nor to help me. We all started that way. Im new in programming ,sorry .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
if(DateTime.Now.Subtract(StartDate).TotalDays%7==0)
```

This will give you the modulus of days and equal 0 every 7 days. It will, however, be time sensistve (if StartDate is 2:00PM, days will be 6 until 2:00PM on day 7). If you are only concerned about the day (not time after midnight) use:

```
 if(DateTime.Now.Date.Subtract(StartDate.Date).TotalDays%7==0)
```

Comment: Okay thanks but how about if I want to determine months ? What is the formula for months since i get the weeks . thank you so much sir.

Comment: if (DateTime.Now.Month>StartDate.Month)

Comment: Wow havnt think about it. Hehe thanks sir you are great  :D im new to this field thanks again.

Comment: The built-in date/time/timespan classes don't normally deal in months for calculating because the number of days in a month varies depending on which months are involved (the TimeSpan structure doesn't even have a Months property), and if February is involved you have to factor in leap year. If you want to do date calculations in months (accurately), you'll likely have to write it yourself.